# Setting DOCTYPE With Server-Side Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, doctype, serverside-javascript

I have a real quick question. I want to set the DOCTYPE for an HTML Page but I need to do it using Server Side Javascript. Every answer I see on this site says "I don't see why you want to do it" but never answers the question (That I could find... please point me in the direction of a post if I am wrong).

The reason it needs to be done is because this is technically being sent as an HTML email. I am using ExactTarget and they won't allow me to type anything above the starting  < HTML > tag. If I try to establish the DOCTYPE after it, it gets simply removed.

Now I DO have access to server side javascript before the email renders. I need to set this DOCTYPE because I am trying to set < td > tags to "display:block" and this will not work with the default DOCTYPE. So basically I need to write some script AFTER the opening < html > tag that will set the doctype for the page (email).

I wish to use the following DOCTYPE but if this is unwise feel free to advise:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >
```

Also here is the CSS not working with the current Doctype:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
      td {display:block !important;}
  }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <table bgcolor="#0033CC" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
           <td>Top Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>Bottom Content</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

When I say server side Javascript here is my syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
  *** MY SCRIPT ***
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "serverside javascript"? Like `node.js`?

Comment: Why in heaven's name would you want to set a `td` to be `display: block`?!

Comment: *"Now I DO have access to server side javascript before the email renders."* Huh? Rendering is a client-side activity, not a server-side activity.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you hover over the tag "serverside-javascript", there seems to be a description. I'm not exactly sure what it means though...

Comment: @Ian: I know what server-side JavaScript is. I don't see that it has any connection to the question, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahh alright, sorry. I took it as a weird statement.

Comment: I've revised my post. SSJ basically gives directions to data before the HTML begins loading. Its very common in ExactTarget as we pre-process data to be dynamically inserted into emails before the HTML loads. 

The reason I want to set my < td > to "display:block" is so they stack on top of one another for responsive design purposes. If you've done HTML for email this will make sense... It's terrible but it is what we have to do unless you have better ideas. DIVs do not work. It is a 2 column layout that needs to stack. Aligning tables will not work in my situation either. 

Thanks all!

Comment: More info on SSJ + ExactTarget: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/  They also have proprietary language called "AMPscript" which is essentially server side scripting. You don't need to worry about this, this is just for your reference. \

Comment: Is there any SSJ to append a doctype before HTML... I know this is really Client-Side but I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

If ExactTarget won't let you output anything prior to the starting `<html>` tag, then you can't do this. The doctype *has* to come before that.

Comment: Yeah , I was hoping for like a document.setDoctype() or something similar.

Comment: @DigitalMC: Ah. Sorry to say, I don't believe there's anything like that.